# Podfile: Path of local pod relative to Projectpath possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to add local pods to my objective c iOS project. Is there a way to use the rootpath of my project as relative path?
The only way I got it to work is by using something like this:

```
pod 'ObjCPod', :path => '~/Documents/iOS-Projects/MyApp/libraries/LocalPod/'
```

This wouldn't work if I moved the Project folder or tried to build the project on another machine.

I would like to have something like this:

```
pod 'ObjCPod', :path => '$(SRCROOT)/libraries/LocalPod/'
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yeah, it worked perfectly. thank you very much

Comment: Your welcome, I am glad to help you, best regards

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that, I have a project that use cocoapods and have custom pods in it, in the folder where you have your PodFile put your libraries folder and then modify your podFile to

```
pod 'ObjCPod', :path => 'libraries/LocalPod/'
```

Should work,
Hope this helps

Comment: $(SRCROOT) is defined by/in Xcode. This file is processed by the cocoapod command line tool `pod` to process the project files accessed by Xcode.  Typically it is executed _from_ the directory the Podfile is in as well. If something was a peer of the project, you could use `:path => '../LocalPod/'`