# Swift: How to link pod to my own framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I was trying to create a framework that uses a pod, when I run the command `pod lib lint` to validate my `.podspec` file i get:

> ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/*/Desktop/Developer/*/*/Models/*.swift:8:8: error: no such module 'SwiftyUserDefaults'

How to link a pod to my framework

I get a warning too I think it's because my repository is private so I'm reading a tutorial, but I also get another error I do not know what it means:

> ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.

What is?

Ir the full message:

```
- WARN  | url: The URL (https://github.com/*/*) is not reachable.
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use `--verbose` for more information.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
- NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild:  /Users/*/Desktop/Developer/*/*/Models/EMConnectedPeripheral.swift:8:8: error: no such module 'SwiftyUserDefaults'
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842837/podfile-path-of-local-pod-relative-to-projectpath-possible/44855971#44855971 may help you

Answer (score 3):

Add in the `.podspec` file:
`spec.dependency 'NameOfDependency'`